# Sum of specific number of rows for a id in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am pretty new to excel formulas. I want to calculate the sum of prices for every unique id. Using `SUMIF` I was able to do that for every unique id but I only want to calculate the sum of a number of rows for that id.

```
=SumIF(A:A;C2;B:B)
```

Sample data is attached. Actual data set is quite large. For Example, For Id 1, I only want to calculate the sum of first 3 rows (Column price) corressponding to that id, for id 2 the sum of first 4 rows and so on.

**Sample data:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/530VU.png]

Comment: Then you would first have to determine the range you want your formula to work on. If I do your logic, and take first 4 rows to check for ID2, there will be no matches found.

Comment: Thats right, do you have nay ideas how can I define the range here

Comment: You can use `Vloopkup` combined with `Indirect()` on the result to include the cell values into your reference. Like `=Countif(Indirect("A1:A"&D4),C2,Indirect("B1:B"&D4))` where you can replace D4 with the vlookup

Answer (score 0):

This formula works for sorted and non sorted data:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$20)/($A$2:$A$20=C2),D2)),C2,$B$2:INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$20)/($A$2:$A$20=C2),D2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Slight modification to check for cases where there are fewer matches than the number of rows specified (or no matches):
`=IFERROR(SUMIF($A$2:INDEX($A$1:$A$20,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$20)/($A$2:$A$20=C2),MIN(D2,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,C2)))),C2,$B$2:$B$20),0)`

Answer (score 0):

Enter this as an array formula (`ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`):

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ROW($A$2:$A$20)>SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$20=C2,ROW($A$2:$A$20),FALSE),MIN(D2,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,C2))),0,1),IF($A$2:$A$20=C2,1,0),$B$2:$B$20),0)
```